# C#: How to create new struct object with loop

Tags: c#, struct

How can I create new struct objects via a loop. Foreach through a list's elements for e.g.?

Here is my struct:

```
public struct TestStruct
{
    public int value1;
    public int value2;
    public List<string> firststructlist;

    public TestStruct(int bab, int bob)
    {
        value1 = bab;
        value2 = bob;
        firststructlist = new List<string>();
     }
     
    public void Add(string value)
    {
        if (firststructlist == null)
            firststructlist = new List<string>();
        firststructlist.Add(value);
    }
}
```

It seems OK, I can create new objects "manually"

```
TestStruct second = new TestStruct(1, 2);
second.value1 = 8;
second.value2 = 9;
second.firststructlist.Add("panapinom");
second.firststructlist.Add("zsakfos");
```

But failed to do it via loop during run-time.
I imagined something like this (this does not work of course):

```
foreach (string something in anything)
{
    TestStruct "something" = new TestStruct(1, 2);
    // new TestStruct for all "something" in the list
}`enter code here`
```

Please help!

Comment: Yep, as the dupe suggests - this is what `Dictionary<string,TestStruct>` is for

Comment: Every time you think you have to use something like `Variable1`, `Variable2` etc... it means you need an array/list/whatever collection